# Deployment Error when deploying a Nexus war into Wildfly via Docker

Tags: docker, wildfly, nexus

I'm trying to deploy a nexus war into Wildfly using Docker, but I'm getting this error

```
2024-02-07 14:52:45,828 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "file.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"file.war\".INSTALL" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of file\"file.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Failed to link com/vaadin/flow/component/grid/ColumnGroup (Module \"deployment.file.war\" from Service Module Loader): com/vaadin/flow/component/grid/ColumnGroup has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"file.war\".WeldStartService",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"file.war\".beanmanager"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"file.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"file.war\".WeldStartService, jboss.deployment.unit.\"file.war\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"file.war\".batch.artifact.factory is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"file.war\".beanmanager]"
    ]
}
```

Here are the JDK and environment details I'm using:

JDK: 8
Wildfly Version: 15.0.1.Final
MSSQL JDBC Version: 12.4.2.jre8

Comment: Your code is compiled with an higher java version than the runtime uses

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: That could be the solution, you mean the java version in pom.xml right, because on this file, I'm currently using 11, I'll downgrade it to 8

Comment: downgrading my .war deployment from 11 to 8 did not work, I'm still getting the same error message

Comment: *com/vaadin/flow/component/grid/ColumnGroup has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0)* It is not your code, it is the vaadin dependency

Comment: hey sorry for my late reply, it took a while to install, changing vaadin dependecy version is causing more incompatibilites. I need to ask my senior